# generar reportes (excel o pdf) django

Tags: django, excel, pdf

hola buenas quiero generar algún tipo de reporte a partir de los resultados que generan mis búsquedas, todo esto de un proyecto web en django,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

acá mi views:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cual seria la forma mas sencilla de generar dichos reportes?, de antemano gracias.

Comment: no termino de entender qué es lo que quieres extraer en un reporte

Comment: Quieres que la secciòn de resultados ràpidos se despliegue en un EXCEL o PDF?

Comment: básicamente que  los resultados generados por la búsqueda se puedan descargar en pdf o excel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar dataTables Te dejo el link: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html y un ejemplo de como lo puedes integrar a tu template

Tu archivo js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#resultadosBusqueda').dataTable({
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
        ]
    }
   });
  });
```

tu template

```
{% if query %} /*Tu context o diccionario que retorna tu consulta*/



/*id="resultadosBusqueda" lo llamas en tu .js*/
            <table id="resultadosBusqueda" class="display nowrap " cellspacing="100" width="auto">

             <thead>
                <tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th> Folio</th>
                    <th> Nombre </th>
                    <th> Edad </th>
                    <th> Genero</th>
                  </tr>
                </tr>
             </thead>

            <tbody>
      {% for item in query %}



                <tr>

                    <td><br>{{ item.folio }}</td>
                    <td><br>{{ item.nombre}</td>
                    <td><br>{{ item.edad}}</td>
                    <td >
                        {{ item.genero}}</a>

                    </td>
                </tr>

      {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
                <br>
                <br>

        {% endif %}
            </tbody>

            </table>
```

Comment: muchas gracias precisamente lo que buscaba